# In what specific ways does the content differ between the standard edition and the student edition of The Apologetics Study Bible?

Tags: apologetics, bible-commentary

My question is how to compare and contrast the contents of [The Apologetics Study Bible](http://www.apologeticsbible.com/#the-apologetics-study-bible-modal%20The%20Apologetics%20Study%20Bible) and [The Apologetics Study Bible for Students](http://www.apologeticsbible.com/#the-apologetics-study-bible-for-students-modal%20The%20Apologetics%20Study%20Bible%20for%20Students).  It is clear from the title that the latter is targeted toward students, but my understanding was that the average Christian adult is no better versed in subjects such as apologetics, philosophy of religion, natural theology, etc., than the average Christian student.  I want to know why a potential buyer/reader would choose one over the other, apart from their age or schooling status.

The above link offer a small clue.  From the standard edition:

> More than 100 articles relate biblical truth to science, history, archaeology, psychology, philosophy, and other critical subjects. Strategically placed alongside the text of Scripture.

From the student edition:

> In addition to the complete HCSB text and dozens of articles collected from today’s most popular youth leaders, including general editor Sean McDowell, this new study Bible also includes:
>   Two-color design-intensive layout on every page for the visual generation
>   Sixty “Twisted Scriptures” explanations
>   Fifty “Bones & Dirt” entries (archaeology meets apologetics)
>   Fifty “Notable Quotes”
>   Twenty-five “Tactics” against common anti-Christian arguments
>   Twenty “Personal Stories” of how God has worked in real lives
>   Twenty “Top Five” lists to help remember key apologetics topics

However, it is very difficult to find any more specific information, as it seems few people have read both editions.

How does the Biblical commentary in each edition of The Apologetics Study Bible differ, in terms of scope (the number of topics addressed), depth (how thoroughly addressed topics are explored, i.e., does one go further into point->counterpoint->countercounterpoint->etc. than the other), focus (are some types of topics a heavier focus in one than the other), etc.?  Does one include more non-apologetic commentary than the other to fill the space of whatever content it lacks?

Comment: This question might be closed because it is not strictly about the beliefs of Christians. You might want to direct your question to the publisher of the book in question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not [one of the topics that can be addressed in questions here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @guest37 Who cares if it's not an exact match for the general categories listed there? It's a perfectly good question in the scope of expertise and format that we like; additionally it falls somewhere between answerable with objective facts  and a little bit of "[good subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)". Some expertise applied to this question should be able to provide a quite satisfactory answer without creating the kind of debate problems we avoid by closing some kinds of question.

Comment: @Caleb - Ok.  I retracted my close vote.